# Can we define types inside a function in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I'm new to OCaml. I want to define a type that is used in one function only. I don't want to make it available outside that function. Can we define it inside that function? Or is there some other way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 15):

If you have recent version of OCaml, you could use a local module:

```
let f x =
  let module Local = struct
    type t = A | B
  end in
  ...
```

It may be more natural to define the type at top level and just leave it out of the `.mli`, though: that would keep it globally hidden, although it would be visible to other code in the file.

Comment: And you can open the local module.